# Delete multiple table in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

How to delete multiple tables in single query in DB2?

Answer (score 0):

DROP TABLE tableName1,tableName2;

Comment: I tried exactly the way you said for two test tables and I ran into -104 error saying I used Illegal token.         DROP TABLE TEST1,TEST2;

Answer (score 0):

If you tables are in hierarchy - you can use
**DROP TABLE HIERARCHY** operation, if they aren't - unfortunatly, you can't delete tables in single query and you may delete them separatly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things but it never worked, Ultimately this is what works.

```
db2 "Select 'DROP TABLE ', tabname, ';' from syscat.tables where owner='DB2INST1'" >> filename
```

This would essentially generate a file called filename, It will have the drop table command for all the tables, You have to open this file up and REMOVE all the tables you don't want to drop and leave the ones which you need. Verify again.

Run this using:

```
db2 -tvf filename.
```